# Where can I find table of python's default abstract types?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, one may encounter various types, protocols, or interfaces such as sequences, buffers, and iterable. However, finding information about all of them in one place can be difficult as the documentation tends to have them dispersed throughout various locations rather than having a clear and concise summary or table.

I am looking for a comprehensive resource that lists and explains the different types, protocols, or interfaces in Python such as sequences, buffers, and iterable. Additionally, I am wondering what the proper terminology is for these concepts as I currently refer to them informally as "those python abstract interfaces."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html

I found this table that provides definitions for a variety of the aforementioned protocols, including iterable, sequence, and many others.